# Will CDialog:SetTimer() lock up a thread if KillTimer() is never called?

Tags: c++, mfc, thread-safety

```
BOOL CMemeDlg::PreTranslateMessage(MSG* pMsg)
{
    CString csMessage;
    if (pMsg->message == WM_KEYDOWN)
    {
        if (pMsg->wParam == VK_HOME)
        {
            KillTimer(TIMER_ID_FIELD); 
            SetTimer(TIMER_ID_FIELD, 500, NULL); 
            return true;
        }
    }

    return CDialog::PreTranslateMessage(pMsg);
}
```

In this code snippit will the timer lock up a thread, assuming that there's no other `KillTimer` somewhere else in the code flow?

Answer (score 2):

No. Just every 500msec the `WM_TIMER` message will be sent.

If the handler is lightweight you will not even see any activity in the task manager.

Answer (score 2):

If there is no `KillTimer()` at all, `SetTimer()` will simply reset an existing timer if it already exists.  So you are not going to be over-burdening the thread with multiple timers.

The `WM_TIMER` message is a *synthesized message*.  When message retrieval is performed via `(Get|Peek)Message()` and there are no actual messages available in the queue (or if message retrieval is filtering for `WM_(SYS)TIMER` specifically), then the timer is checked and an actual `WM_TIMER` message is generated in the message queue only if the timer has elapsed.

So, as long as you are processing those `WM_TIMER` messages properly, you won't over-burden your thread with unnecessary timer processing.

Just be careful that you don't perform a lot of message retrievals that ignore `WM_TIMER`, otherwise you can fill up your message queue (see [Even though mouse-move, paint, and timer messages are generated on demand, it’s still possible for one to end up in your queue](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20130523-00/?p=4273) and [Why is my message queue full of WM_TIMER messages?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20160624-00/?p=93745).